# How to use line break without using html tags?

Tags: php

This is my code:

```
$blogid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']); 

if((isset($_POST['comment']))&&(!(trim($_POST['comment'])==FALSE))&&(isset($_SESSION['userid']))){

   $comment = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comment']); 
   $querycomment = "INSERT INTO `comment` (`userid`, `blogid`, `body`) VALUES ( '".$_SESSION['userid']."', '".$blogid."', '".$comment."');";
   $rowchat = mysql_query($querymess,$db_con) or die("Failed: " . mysql_error() );

}

<form method="post" action="blog.php?id=<?php echo $blogid; ?>" >
<textarea name="comment" ></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="send" name="submit" />
</form>
```

When a User comment this:

```
This
is
my
world
```

Then in the comments list appears this:

```
This is my world
```

Why doesn't line break works ?

Comment: Looks like "How to use HTML without HTML" question

Comment: You could wrap the output in <pre> tags

Answer (score 5):

Because line breaks are saved as `\n`.

You can use the PHP function [`nl2br($string)`](http://www.php.net/nl2br) before echo'ing the string.

```
<?php
    $string = "This\nis\nmy\nworld";
    echo nl2br($string);
?>
```